# How to create a navbar with 2 collapse menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My codes are working fine on mobile view but on desktop right side Links are getting out of nav-bar. i am trying to create nav bar with Brand in center, search bar on left and links on right. and how to move hambuger bar on left  and search on right side on mobile view .. (sorry for my english)

```css
.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    z-index:3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-2">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
      </button>
    </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left" id="navbar-collapse-1">
     <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
     </form>
     </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: just place the code for button search before hamburger in your html

Comment: The question is not duplicate.. The subject of the question is.. The OP want something different of what actually has been asked @ZimSystem

Comment: The question was changed, but the alignment issue is duplicate as well. Read the other answers and the solution works: https://www.codeply.com/go/fb9pU5evMu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `menu-1` class or call it whatever you want to the `button`

```
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle menu-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-2">
```

then add this to your css:

```
.menu-1 {
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

**Update:** to handle search issue remove `width: 100` and increase `left` for `.navbar-brand` like this:

```
.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

and add this css also:

```
@media (max-width:767px){
    a.navbar-brand {
        left: 45%;
  }
}
```

check the updated [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Alaa_Mh/n1y9c7r5/)

Comment: I tried not working..

Comment: try my comment .. @NIrajBhaskar

Comment: @SahilDhir I tried but not working ...

Comment: I updated the answer with jsfiddle check it

Comment: Thanks you so much ... but how to fix ul links on right side, how to fix that alignment ?

Comment: add this to css `.navbar-right {
    padding-right: 15px;
}`

Comment: Thanksss ... one more thing search box is not working on click cause Brand position is absolute .. how to move brand center without changing positions to absolute ?

Comment: I've updated the solution, if this is what you want please mark my answer as the correct answer

Comment: I've already explained in the other answer and shown example: http://www.codeply.com/go/fb9pU5evMu

Answer (score 1):

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .nav_bar_align .navbar-brand{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
 }
 .nav_bar_align .nav_humber{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top nav_bar_align" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle nav_humber" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-2">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
      </button>
    </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left" id="navbar-collapse-1">
     <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
     </form>
     </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: That's did it Thanks... but how to fix right side links?

Comment: Right side links means i didn't get you can u please explain i will help you.

Comment: Search box is not working on click cause Brand position is absolute .. how to move brand center without changing positions to absolute ?